# How to sync Sharepoint online site calendar with outlook?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, outlook

I want to sync SharePoint online site's calendar events tasks to Outlook.

I have tried **Connect to outlook** button in Calendar ribbon but it's not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

usually right after you click that button there is an authorization pop up in outlook that needs to be okeyed.

Look around for that popup looking at the application bar below if something is blinking.

Have you tried different browsers?